# Image of a closed set is closed under bounded linear transformation between Banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, open-map

Let $A,B$ be Banach spaces and let $T:A \to B$ be a surjective, bounded, linear operator. Let $A_1$ be a non-empty subset of $A$, then:

$T(A_1)$ is closed if and only if $A_1+ \textrm{ker}(T)$ is closed.

I have shown that if $A_1+ \textrm{ker} (T)$ is closed, then $T(A_1)$ is closed, but am unsure of how to proceed in the other direction. Note that we know that $T(A \setminus [A_1 + \textrm{ker}(T)]) = B \setminus T(A_1)$. Figured the reverse direction could be proved using some modification of the Open Mapping Theorem or Closed Graph theorem, but not sure how to tackle this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $T(A_1)$ is closed. Let $\{x_n\} \subset A_1$, $\{y_n\} \subset ker(T)$ and $x_n +y_n \to z$. Since T is continuous we get $Tx_n =Tx_n +Ty_n \to Tz$. Thus $T(z)$ is the limit of the sequence $\{Tx_n\}$ which lies in $T(A_1)$. It follows that $Tz=Tw$ for some $w \in A_1$. But then $z=w+(z-w) \in A_1 +ker (T)$. This proves that $A_1 +ker (T)$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$A_1' = T^{-1}(T(A_1)) = \{ y \in A \mid T(y) \in T(A_1) \} ; \tag 1$

clearly,

$A_1 \subset A_1', \tag 2$

now if $w \in A_1$ and $u \in \ker T$, then

$T(w + u) = T(w) + T(u) = T(w) + 0 = T(w) \in T(A_1), \tag 3$

or

$w + u \in A_1', \tag 4$

which shows that in fact

$A_1 + \ker T \subset A_1'; \tag 5$

and if $z \in A_1'$ then $T(z) \in T(A_1)$, and there is some $x \in A_1$ such that $T(z) =  T(x)$, whence

$T(z - x) = T(z) - T(x) = 0; \tag 6$

thus

$z - x \in \ker T, \tag 7$

or

$z \in x + \ker T \subset A_1 + \ker T, \tag 8$

whence

$A_1' \subset A_1 + \ker T; \tag 9$

(5) and (9) together yield

$A_1' = A_1 + \ker T; \tag{10}$

we now conclude by observing that since

$A_1'= T^{-1}(T(A_1)) \tag{11}$

(as (1) asserts),  and $T(A_1)$ is closed, the continuity of $T$ implies $T^{-1}(T(A_1))$ is closed as well; thus (10) and (11) together yield $A_1 + \ker T$ is closed.